# Custom build type with resources

Tags: android

There is custom build type `mock` and it initialised with `debug`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
    }
    debug {

    }
    mock {
        initWith debug
    }
}
```

There are also `debug` resources under `/debug/res/values/file.xml`.

Without copying `/debug/res/values/file.xml` into `/mock/res/values/file.xml` project doesn't compile as compiler can't find `mock` resources.

Is there way to let gradle know that debug resources should be reused for `mock` build type?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `file.xml` in the `main/res/values` folder to share it across all build types